# Exit from React App and switch to C/C++ program in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, c, create-react-app, vscode-debugger

I was using a React App earlier and now I need to write a C/C++ program but there is an error in "includePath" and it doesn't read the source file "stdio.h".(Using VS Code)
`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\....).`
`cannot open source file "stdio.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers.`

I have terminated all the npm scripts by running  `taskkill -F -IM node.exe` in the node.js terminal
but it still shows error in the header file "stdio.h"